# How to add placeholder to input field via php variable

Tags: custom-field, form-fields-types, fields

In my login form, custom layout fields are displayed by the `$field->input` variable. Unfortunately, those fields are displayed without the placeholder attribute.

Is there any way to add this attribute to the field which is displayed by variable above?

```
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset($fieldset->name) as $name => $field) : ?>
    <?php if ($field->hidden === false) : ?>
        <div class="sc-group">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `hint` is the attribute you're looking for:

```
<field name="name"
       label="Name"
       type="text"
       required="true"
       hint="Placeholder Text"
       default=""
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow below steps

1. Go to components/com_yourcomponent/models/forms
2. Find out the xml file which loads that form.
3. Find the fields where you want to add the place holder text.
4. Use `hint` attribute:`<field name="field_name" label="Field Label" type="text" hint="Placeholder Text"/>`

Answer (score 0):

you can add a hint field in your xlm or you can add a hint value on the fly in your code
here :  $field->hint = some text;

```
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset($fieldset->name) as $name => $field) : 
    $field->hint = JText::_('COM_NAME_FORM_HINT_' . strtoupper($field->fieldname));?>
    <?php if ($field->hidden === false) : ?>
        <div class="sc-group">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please improve your answer to explain how your script works and why it is a good idea. It looks like you merely added one line of code -- please edit your answer to tell us why.  A working solution is just the beginning of a "good post".  Please be generous with your knowledge.  Endeavour to educate/empower the the person who asked the question as well as thousands of future researchers.